# Python - Create multiple lists from elementwise concatenation of two lists

Tags: python

```
lst1 = ['a', 'b', 'c']
lst2 = ['1', '2']

def comb(lst1, lst2):
    for i in lst1:
            new_list = []
            for j in lst2:
                new_list.append(i + '_' + j)
    return new_list
print(comb(lst1, lst2))
```

Gives me:

['c_1', 'c_2']

I am hoping to get:

['a_1', 'a_2']

['b_1', 'b_2']

['c_1', 'c_2']

Could someone please point out the mistake in my code? Thanks!

Comment: Move `new_list` definition outside of the first for loop.

Comment: @PéterLeéh That wont work. It will just create one list with all elements. Not as expected by OP.

Comment: Why were 5 answers offered for something that is clearly a typo?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this

```
res = [[f'{x}_{y}' for y in lst2] for x in lst1]
print(res)
```

**Output:**

```
[['a_1', 'a_2'], ['b_1', 'b_2'], ['c_1', 'c_2']]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
lst1 = ['a', 'b', 'c']
lst2 = ['1', '2']

def comb(lst1, lst2):
    finalList = []
    for i in lst1:
            new_list = []
            for j in lst2:
                new_list.append(i + '_' + j)
            finalList.append(new_list)
    return finalList
    
print(comb(lst1, lst2))
```

`new_list` gets empty every time first for loop is executed. So make another list to store that value before its overwritten and return that second list with all values of `new_list`.

Comment: Better way to do this is using list comprehension. See deadshot's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63591907/8702713) for that.

Answer (score -1):

Just look where *new_list = []* is. You're creating it from scratch in every loop iteration. Just move it before for.

If you just want to see 3 those elements printed, change return into print.

```
lst1 = ['a', 'b', 'c']
lst2 = ['1', '2']

def comb(lst1, lst2):
    for i in lst1:
        new_list = []
        for j in lst2:
            new_list.append(i + '_' + j)
        print(new_list)
comb(lst1, lst2)
```

Comment: If you replace the print with a return you get only the first result. You need to add each constructed list into another list that then gets returned - see https://stackoverflow.com/a/63591903/7505395

Comment: The best solution is the one written by deadshot https://stackoverflow.com/a/63591907/10815718 .  The solution with print is only direct solution of what States.the.Obvious want to get as output,

Answer (score -1):

try this;

```
lst1 = ['a', 'b', 'c']
lst2 = ['1', '2']
new_list = []
for i in lst1:
    l1=[]
    for j in lst2:
        l1.append(i + '_' + j)
    new_list.append(l1)
print(new_list)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
lst1 = ['a', 'b', 'c']
lst2 = ['1', '2']
for e1 in lst1:
    newList = []
    for e2 in lst2:
        newList.append(e1 + "_" + e2)
    print(newList)


Output:
['a_1', 'a_2']
['b_1', 'b_2']
['c_1', 'c_2']
```